# Eloquent returns multiple instances of the same model

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

When using Eloquent on Laravel, I have a relationship which I can call via:

```
$business = $this->business()->first();
```

Unfortunatley each time this code is run it returns a new instance of the related model. e.g.

```
$business1 = $this->business()->first();
$business2 = $this->business()->first();

$business1->value = 5;
```

In the above code `$business2->value` should equal 5, but it doesn't.

Is there a way to force eloquent to return a reference to the model if it already exists in memory rather than creating a new one each time?

Comment: why you are not using `$business` after doing  `$business = $this->business()->first();`  and creating instance again?

Comment: A totally separate section of code re-requests the relation from the source model. The sample code just illustrates the basic issue. I was hoping there was a feature in eloquent to stop duplicate models existing.

Comment: Can you tell me what is `business()`, is it a hasMany relation or method?

Comment: Just a normal BelongsTo relation.

Comment: With in a single model, it is a `hasMany-belongsTo` relation, right?

Comment: Another point is, if it is a `belongsTo` and not `belongsToMany` or `hasMany` why you just can not do `$this->business` ?